# Align line graph to xticks on dual axis plot with heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a line graph and a heatmap on a dual axis plot. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, the line graph isn't aligned to the xticks due to the presence of the heatmap, which centers the xticks. How can I shift the line graph to the right by 0.5 so that the data points on the line graph correctly correspond to the xticks?

Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.random((10, 10))
data2 = np.random.random((10))

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
plt.tick_params(bottom='on')
ax = sns.heatmap(data1, cmap=sns.color_palette("Greens", 5))
ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=data2, linewidth=5, ax=ax2)
ax.axis('tight')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Bazingaa's answer below definitely resolves your issue. That said, in the future, if you want your plots to appear a certain way, you should *build them up that way from the beginning*. Don't let matplotlib or seaborn pick what the x-data of your lines should be. Specify the x-data *when you plot the lines in the first place*.

Comment: @PMende: The issue at hand was the centered x-ticks set by the heatmap. I personally like the centered ticks for the heat map as they represent a given square mesh uniquely rather than having the ticks at the edges

Comment: @Bazingaa Seaborn's default is to center the heatmaps - that's correct. Thus, if you want to plot the line with the same x-values, just go and get those x-values to begin with: `x_arr = np.arange(0, data1.shape[1])`.

Comment: I see what you mean now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is one way of doing it.

**Explanation**: The twin axis instance `ax2` has only one line plotted using `sns.lineplot`. You extract that `line` object first. Then you just update (shift) the x-data of that line to the right by `0.5` as you wanted. The `line.get_xdata()` returns you an array of x-values and you simply add `0.5` in a vectorized manner followed by applying the changes using `line.set_xdata`. Add the following lines after your `sns.lineplot()` command.

```
line = ax2.lines[0] # get the line
line.set_xdata(line.get_xdata() + 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the lineplot, it's the heatmap which shows ticks at the wrong positions[*]. You may directly use a matplotlib imshow plot instead, where everything works correctly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data1 = np.random.random((10, 10))
data2 = np.random.random((10))

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))
plt.tick_params(bottom='on')

im = ax.imshow(data1, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Greens",5), aspect="auto")
f.colorbar(im)

ax2 = plt.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=data2, linewidth=5, ax=ax2)
ax.axis('tight')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

[*] By "wrong position" I mean that the ticks do not appear at the position on the axes that they seem to label. I.e. the data units of the ticks are not identical to the values shown in the labels.

In case of the heatmap being plotted to `ax`, printing

```
print(*ax.get_xticklabels())
```

results in

```
Text(0.5, 0, '0') Text(1.5, 0, '1') Text(2.5, 0, '2') Text(3.5, 0, '3') Text(4.5, 0, '4') Text(5.5, 0, '5') Text(6.5, 0, '6') Text(7.5, 0, '7') Text(8.5, 0, '8') Text(9.5, 0, '9')
```

Here you can see that the first ticklabel is positionned at `x=0.5`, but shows `'0'` as label. I.e. all positions are shifted by 0.5 compared to their labels.

In case of the `imshow` plot, (after drawing the plot, `f.canvas.draw()`), the printed labels are

```
Text(-2.0, 0, '-2') Text(0.0, 0, '0') Text(2.0, 0, '2') Text(4.0, 0, '4') Text(6.0, 0, '6') Text(8.0, 0, '8') Text(10.0, 0, '10')
```

Here labels and positions are consistent.

Comment: If I just use `im = ax.imshow(data1, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Greens",5), aspect="auto")` without plotting the line in your code, the ticks still appear at the same positions as in the plot generated using `sns.heatmap`, i.e., the centered ticks

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes, is that unexpected?

Comment: No, but you wrote "it's the heatmap which shows ticks at the wrong positions". That's why I wrote that the ticks are shown at the **same** positions by both imshow and heatmap

Comment: This is certainly a very clean solution! Could you please elaborate on how the heatmap showed ticks at the wrong positions? How would I be able to tell?

Comment: @Bazingaa and Ernest I updated the answer with some explanation; hope that is clearer now.