# Plot lineplot on top of seaborn heatmap using same axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have seaborn heatmap and I would like to plot a lineplot on top of it while using the same x and y axis that the heatmap is using.

I expected the line to behave like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781245/align-line-graph-to-xticks-on-dual-axis-plot-with-heatmap) and take up most of the space of the heatmap, but instead the output I got was [the following plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TLPK.png) where it only occupied a small section of the heatmap. How can I make the line take up most of the space in the heatmap?

Below is the minimal working example that produced the plot I linked above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

num = 11
a = np.eye(num)
x = np.round(np.linspace(0, 1, num=num), 1)
y = np.round(np.linspace(0, 1, num=num), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=x, index=y)

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar=False)
ax.axes.invert_yaxis()
sns.lineplot(x=x, y=y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x=x*num, y=y*num)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps just a simple fix here:

```
sns.lineplot(x=x*num, y=y*num)
```

[image]